# Show the following inequality holds (with Taylor Approximation)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, gradient-descent

Consider a sequence of vector $x_1, x_2, ..., x_N$. Show that for 
$$
\bar{x} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i
$$
the following inequality holds
$$
f(\bar{x}) - f(x^*)  \leq \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N <x_i - x^*, \nabla f(x_i)>
$$
where $x^*$ minimizes $f$ which is a convex function mapping from $R^n$ to $R^m$.

Comment: Is the range of $f$ $\mathbb R^{m}$ or$\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 0):

By convexity,
$$f(x_i) + \langle x^* - x_i, \nabla f(x_i) \rangle \le f(x^*)$$
for each $i$.
Summing over all $i$ and dividing by $N$ yields
$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N f(x_i) - f(x^*) \le \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \langle x_i - x^*, \nabla f(x_i)\rangle.$$
Finally, note that $\frac{1}{N}
 \sum_{i=1}^N f(x_i) \ge f(\bar{x})$.